# Unable to use shared preference values in class A extends BroadcastReceiver , Android

Tags: android

I am Unable to use shared preference values in a class-say Class A that extends BroadcastReceiver. I do a commit in another class- an activity class, now I want to retrieve those set of values inside Class A that extends BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Context` in the parameters of your `BroadcastReceiver`method

```
    /**
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
    {
        context.getSharedPreferences( name, mode );
```