# How to use shared preference data in different classes in android?

Tags: android

Using shared preferences I saved data in one of the activity Now I want to use that data in another activity how to do that?

Comment: you can get preferences anywhere in your whole application

Comment: did you try searching this before asking this question?

Comment: no research effort what so ever...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PREFS_NAME is the value you stored in shared preference.

```
 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";    

// Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false)
```

Look at [Restoring preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Edited:**To use it among all classes i.e. setter getter method.Perfect use of OOPS.You can call  the value from any class thats 1-line job**

Make a normal class name as ReturningClass.

```
public class ReturningClass {

private static String MY_STRING_PREF = "mystringpref";

private static String MY_INT_PREF = "shareduserid";

public static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {


    return context.getSharedPreferences("UserNameAcrossApplication", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

public static String getMyStringPref(Context context) {

    return getPrefs(context).getString(MY_STRING_PREF, "default");
}

public static int getMyIntPref(Context context) {

    return getPrefs(context).getInt(MY_INT_PREF, 0);
}

public static void setMyStringPref(Context context, String value) {
    // perform validation etc..
    getPrefs(context).edit().putString(MY_STRING_PREF, value).commit();
}

public static void setMyIntPref(Context context, int value) {
    // perform validation etc..
    getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(MY_INT_PREF, value).commit();
}
```

Set your value by calling

```
  ReturningClass.setMyIntPref(mContext,22);
```

Once You have set your sharedPreference.Then just call this method.Just pass the context.from your class

```
 int usersharedpreference=ReturningClass.getMyIntPref(mContext);
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a sharedPreference where you want to add shared data. A little example of code like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("CONSTANT_FILE_NAME",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("isPaid", true);
                editor.commit();
```

And to retrieve that shared data use this code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("CONSTANT_FILE_NAME",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.getBoolean("isPaid",false);
```

Read this from developer site: [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: For some reason I get null...Why?

Answer (score 2):

This link can help you.

[Unable to use shared preference values in class A extends BroadcastReceiver , Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983129/unable-to-use-shared-preference-values-in-class-a-extends-broadcastreceiver-an)

also 
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Answer (score 0):

```
   //decleration
 SharedPreferences saveWord;

//onCreate
saveWord=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityName.this);
String word=saveWord.getBoolean(PREFS_NAME, false);
```

Comment: ...the question is about access from **different** classes... not the same