# Shared Preference values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to use the value of shared preferences from one activity to another activity, like if my pin from pin_activity is set on, the pattern from another activity should be disabled, and show the Toast that "PinService is ON, You can't Make PatternService ON" and vice versa. i am not getting how to use shared preference values. Please help me out in doing this

here is my code for both activities.

```
pin_activity.java

    s2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);


    spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    s2.setChecked(spref.getBoolean("SwitchButton", false));


    s2.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("SwitchButton", s2.isChecked());
            // editor.putString("switch_state", "value");
            //switch_state=editor.putBoolean("SwitchButton", s2.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Pattern_activity.java

```
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
           .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    s1.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleButton", false));
    switch1= sharedPreferences.getBoolean("editor",s1.isChecked() );
    if (switch1== true)
    {
        s1.setEnabled(false);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PinService is ON, You can't Make PatternService ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        s1.setEnabled(true);
    }



    s1.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            //switch1= sharedPreferences.getString("switch_state", null);
            editor.commit();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can always use support class to get and set values to shared preferences, its always easier that way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596851/how-to-use-shared-preference-data-in-different-classes-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same key for your setting.

In your example you use "SwitchButton" to read/write the state of the switch in pin_activity and "editor" to read (supposedly) that same value. Which cannot work.

So extract a key string to a constant like `public static String PIN_STATE = "PIN_STATE";`.

in pin_activity:

```
s2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);


    spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    s2.setChecked(spref.getBoolean(PIN_STATE, false));


    s2.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(PIN_STATE, s2.isChecked());
            // editor.putString("switch_state", "value");
            //switch_state=editor.putBoolean(PIN_STATE, s2.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

in Pattern_activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
           .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    s1.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleButton", false));
    switch1= sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PIN_STATE, s1.isChecked() );
    if (switch1== true)
    {
        s1.setEnabled(false);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PinService is ON, You can't Make PatternService ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        s1.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

And from that on you probably need to do something similar for `PATTERN_STATE` and in general straighten out you button states, as they seem a bit jumbled.